# bootstrap-datepicker onchange event firing in infinite loop upon page load

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using version 1.6.1 of bootstrap-datepicker.  I have the following form field on a JSP page:

```
<input class="datepicker form-control" type="text" name="day" value="<%=day%>" size="10" onchange="return submit_form(this.form,'day');">
```

The intent is to allow a new date to be picked, and upon selection to trigger form submission using the 'onchange' event.

I have the following `<script>` initialization block:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({format: 'mm/dd/yyyy', autoclose: 'true', todayBtn: 'true', todayHighlight: 'true', orientation: 'auto top'});
    });
</script>
```

The issue I'm having is that upon page load, 'submit_form' is called, loading the page again and then 'submit_form' called again, so the page reloads in an infinite loop because it's being submitted in an infinite loop.  This does not happen with version 1.4.0 of the library, so I'm inclined to think it's a bug in the new version.

Can anybody confirm that my use of the component is reasonable (correct) and if there is, in fact, a bug in the updated of bootstrap-datepicker?

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/jneuhaus/pen/MyMPqM) which illustrates the issue.  Notice that upon completion of page loading, the onchange event is immediately fired.  This doesn't happen if I use an earlier version of bootstrap-datepicker.

Comment: Please create a minimal example that shows the issue, perhaps in a JSFiddle, CodePen, or code snippet.

Comment: I have tried but I cannot seem to get jsfiddle to work...

Comment: Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/jneuhaus/pen/MyMPqM) which illustrates the issue.  Notice that upon completion of page loading, the onchange event is immediately fired.  This doesn't happen if I use an earlier version of bootstrap-datepicker.